# ¿Cómo usar un ciclo for para arrojar con la consola la posición de cada una de las letras "p" dentro de una cadena?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, bucle-for, iteradores

Estoy intentando que la consola de `python` me arrojara el mensaje:

```
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: [-indice de la letra "p"]
```

dentro de la cadena `porqueElegiPython`.

La idea es que me arroje el mismo mensaje por cada una de todas las letras `p` dentro de la cadena, sin repetirse tantas veces el mismo numero.

Mi duda es como pasar de esto:

```
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 6
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 13
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 13
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 13
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 13
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 13
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 13
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 13
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 42
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 42
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 42
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 42
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 42
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 62
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 62
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 62
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 62
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 62
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 62
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 62
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 62
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 62
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 62
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 62
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 62
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 62
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 62
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 62
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 62
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 62
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 62
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 62
```

a esto:

```
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 6
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 13
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 42
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 62
```

LES DEJO MI CIDIGO Y DESDE YA MUCHAS GRACIAS!!!

```
  porqueElegiPython = "Elegi python porque tiene una sintaxis un poco mas sencilla y porque no se relaciona directamente con el desarroyo front end, aunque puede utilizarse para tales propositos"

for i in range(6, 164):
    print(f"la letra p aparece en la posicion numero:", porqueElegiPython.index("p", i))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa un ciclo `for` para recorrer cada letra del `string`. Si la letra es "p", imprimes el mensaje, si no, continúas a la siguiente letra.

```
porqueElegiPython = "Elegi python porque tiene una sintaxis un poco mas sencilla y porque no se relaciona directamente con el desarroyo front end, aunque puede utilizarse para tales propositos"

for i in range(0, len(porqueElegiPython)):
   if porqueElegiPython[i] == "p":
       print(f"la letra p aparece en la posicion numero:", i)
```

Salida:

```
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 6
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 13
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 42
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 62
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 133
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 150
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 161
la letra p aparece en la posicion numero: 164
```

Otra alternativa:

```
for index, letra in enumerate(porqueElegiPython):
    if letra == "p":
        print(f"la letra p aparece en la posicion numero:", index)
```

o bien en una sola línea pero menos legible:

```
porqueElegiPython = "Elegi python porque tiene una sintaxis un poco mas sencilla y porque no se relaciona directamente con el desarroyo front end, aunque puede utilizarse para tales propositos"

message = f"la letra p aparece en la posicion numero:";

[print(message, i) for i,letra in enumerate(porqueElegiPython) if letra == "p"]
```

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias!!! Me ayudo mucho